# reserve space for a particular position in all rows of a file through unix shell script

Tags: bash, shell, unix, awk, scripting

I am having a list of students in a file and i want to make a script like:

```
student.txt
Rambavbusukhde
Shobit
Maa
```

below is the script i prepare:

```
cat student.txt |awk '{print "create synonym classa."$1 " for classb."$1";"}'
```

The output :

```
create synonym classa.Rambavbusukhde for classb.Rambavbusukhde;
create synonym classa.Shobit for classb.Shobit;
create synonym classa.Maa for classb.Maa;
```

but i want to reserve the space for all the student name before the word "for" to 30 character so that output looks like:

```
create synonym classa.Rambavbusukhde for classb.Rambavbusukhde;
create synonym classa.Shobit         for classb.Shobit;
create synonym classa.Maa            for classb.Maa;
```

Note: I am not able to show the space between name and word "for". All "for" should be looks in one line only

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use printf satement of awk to provide the formating"

```
awk '{printf "create synonym classa.%-30s for classb.%s;\n",$1,$1}' student.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

Just pass the output of awk command to `column -t` command,

```
$ awk '{print "create synonym classa."$1 " for classb."$1";"}' file | column -t
create  synonym  classa.Rambavbusukhde  for  classb.Rambavbusukhde;
create  synonym  classa.Shobit          for  classb.Shobit;
create  synonym  classa.Maa             for  classb.Maa;
```